# (TestNg) When i change the location in base class of driver location it is not reflecting it is showing IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng, testng-eclipse

In BASE CLASS

```java
public class BaseClass {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void getDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\Assignments\\Tasks\\Framework_Task\\adactinhotelapp\\adactinhotelapp\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void launchUrl(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

In then while I running it

```java
public class SampleClassWithTestNg extends BaseClass {
    static BaseClass global = new BaseClass();
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void driverConfiguring() {
        global.getDriver();
        global.launchUrl("http://adactinhotelapp.com/");
    }
}
```

but I'm getting error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\Assignments\Tasks\Framework_Task\adactinhotelapp\Drivers\chromedriver.exe

[I changed the location in base class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMNG4.jpg),

[but it is showing the exception and change is not affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGzPt.jpg)

Comment: Can you please confirm that the chromedriver.exe path is correct or not?

Comment: It's correct... !! Path I have given is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the `chromedriver.exe` file because the exact code is working fine for me.**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:
```

The above error, clearly indicate that there is some issue with the `chromedriver.exe` file.

As per the path mention, I can assume you are using windows, so make sure:

1. `Chromrdriver` path is correct - If possible provide screenshot of the directory with path.
2. You have permission to execute the `chromedriver`.
3. Download the correct `Chromedriver` version for platform:

   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
   https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Note: For ubuntu and Mac the chromedriver shouldn't contain .exe as extension.

---

**You can also remove the hassle of defining**
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");`
by using **WebDriverManager**.

To use WebDriverManager from tests in a Maven project, you need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml (Java 8 or upper required).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Just use:**
`WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`
instead of `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");`

Ref: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager